# How to calculate the euclidean distance in R between two matrices each with unequal dimensions

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

How to calculate the euclidean distance in R between Matrix A and Matrix B as per below:

I have two matrices that is Matrix A and Matrix B

Matrix A:

```
     [,1][,2]
[1,]   1   1   
[2,]   1   2   
[3,]   2   1   
[4,]   2   2   
[5,]   10  1   
[6,]   10  2   
[7,]   11  1   
[8,]   11  2   
[9,]   5   5   
[10,]  5   6
```

Matrix B:

```
     [,1][,2][,3][,4][,5][,6]
[1,]   2   1   5   5  10   1
[2,]   1   1   2   1  10   1
[3,]   5   5   5   6  11   2
[4,]   2   2   5   5  10   1
[5,]   2   1   5   6  5    5
[6,]   2   2   5   5  11   1
[7,]   2   1   5   5  10   1
[8,]   1   1   5   6  11   1
[9,]   2   1   5   5  10   1
[10,]  5   6   11  1  10   2


I want the Result matrix (euclidean distance) to be as per below:

        [1,]  [,2]  [,3]

    [1,] 1.00  5.66  9.00
    [2,] 1.00  1.41
    [3,]
    [4,]
    [5,]
    [7,]
    [8,]
    [9,]
    [10]
```

For every row in Matrix A, calculate the euclidean distance to every two column in each row Matrix B.

For example, to get the answer for the following in result matrix:

```
        [,1]
    [1,]
```

The calculation is:

```
    A(1,1) - From Matrix A
    B(2,1) - From Matrix B

    = sqrt((xA -xB)^2 + (yA -yB)^2)
    = sqrt((1-2)^2 + (1-1)^2)
    = 1.00

    xA and yA from Matrix A
    xB and yB from Matrix B
```

To get the answer for the following in result matrix:

```
        [,2]
    [1,] 5.66
```

The calculation is:

```
    A(1,1) - From Matrix A
    B(5,5) - From Matrix B

    = sqrt((xA -xB)^2 + (yA -yB)^2)
    = sqrt((1-5)^2 + (1-5)^2)
    = 5.66
```

To get the answer for the following in result matrix:

```
        [,3]
    [1,] 9.00
```

The calculation is:

```
    A(1,1) - From Matrix A
    B(10,1) - From Matrix B

    = sqrt((xA -xB)^2 + (yA -yB)^2)
    = sqrt((1-10)^2 + (1-1)^2)
    = 9.00
```

Currently, my codes below only works if Matrix A and B are of equal dimensions:

```
    distance <- function(MatrixA, MatrixB) {
      resultMatrix <- matrix(NA, nrow=dim(MatrixA)[1], ncol=dim(MatrixB)[1])
      for(i in 1:nrow(MatrixB)) {
         resultMatrix[,i] <- sqrt(rowSums(t(t(MatrixA)-MatrixB[i,])^2))
      }
         resultMatrix
      }
```

Comment: Are you asking for the correct approach (in psuedocode) or the complete code itself? Ideally, you should ask for help with the approach, give the coding a try, and ask for corrections afterwards. I can help with the approach if you like.

Comment: Hi @BrishnaBatool i have the code but it only works if Matrix A and B are of the same dimensions. I will edit my question and insert the codes. For now yes I would love to know your approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your for loop, so it calculates for each row all three columns of the result matrix:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(matA)) 
{
  resultMatrix[i,1] <- sqrt(rowSums((t(MatrixA[i,])-MatrixB[i,1:2])^2))
  resultMatrix[i,2] <- sqrt(rowSums((t(MatrixA[i,])-MatrixB[i,3:4])^2))
  resultMatrix[i,3] <- sqrt(rowSums((t(MatrixA[i,])-MatrixB[i,5:6])^2))

}
```

Generalized for an arbitrary number of columns:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(MatrixA)) 
{
  for(j in 1:((dim(MatrixB)[2])/2)) 
  {  
    k = (j * 2) - 1
    resultMatrix[i,j] <- sqrt(rowSums((t(MatrixA[i,])-MatrixB[i,k:(k+1)])^2))
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi this gives the correct solution thank you very much. Do you have any other suggestions on how to simplify the for loop if the number of columns is very large and if the result matrix has a very large number of columns? and how do I adjust this part of the code so that I can automatically get the number of columns using the code               ncol=dim(MatrixB)[1]

Comment: Instead of the three sstatements, you could add a nested for loop that would iterate over half the number of columns in matrixB, and in each iteration, perform 'resultMatrix[i,j] <- sqrt(rowSums((t(MatrixA[i,])-MatrixB[i,j:j+1])^2))'

Comment: I have added that to the answer.

Comment: That is exactly what i am looking for. Thank you so much for your help Brishna, really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi Brishna, I just realized that the third column of the result matrix for the simplified for loops doesn't give the correct answer. What could possibly the problem

Comment: Ah yes, the inner loop should increment j by 2 each time instead of 1. I'll fix it

Comment: Fixed @DataMiningStudent

Comment: Thank you so much, i've tested it and it works perfectly fine now.